# How to navigate between child Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I understand how to navigate between fragments using Jetpack's `Navigation Component`, but I haven't been able to find is how to navigate from one child fragment to another child fragment.

The following is what I've done so far:

https://pastebin.com/dNQ0Ep4S the code example is pretty big so sum it up,  I'm trying to do is" A>B and Ba>Bb". `Ba` is a fragment inside of fragment `B`. I'm not sure how to set up the `nav graph` for something like that

The navigation works until the `home` fragment. The `bot nav` just doesn't seem to work. It always displays the pending layout. Another thing I tried was setting the `nav graph` of the `home` to the same one used for the `login` and adding the pending and history fragments to the nav file without any actions. But the `home` loads the `login`, the tabs work, but they're replacing the `home` fragment instead of being placed in the `home nav host`.

**Update**

I managed to find the problem, but I'm stuck trying to find a solution.

So `B` seems to be getting the `navhost` for `A` when I setup the `botnavview` to the `navcontroller`. So calling `NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);` from `B` returns the `navhost` of `A`. I'm at a lost here. If I do this `NavController navController2 = Navigation.findNavController(currentActivity, R.id.homeNavHostFragmentContainer);` (`homeNavHostFragmentContainer` being the `navhost`for `B`) still returns the `navhost` for `A`. For some reason, I can't get a reference to `B`'s `navhost`.

Comment: How did you add the child Fragment in the first place? Via a nested `NavHostFragment` (which is absolutely supported) or via a `FragmentTransaction`, etc.? That method will determine how you do the replacement

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'll update my question. What I got seems to be a little too vague.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Question updated. By the way, I just realized who you are. I'm not worthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I misunderstood how `NavHostFragment.findNavController()` functions. Fragment `B` is not a `navhost` is just a regular `Fragment`. The `navhost` for `B` is a child of `B`. The argument for `findNavController()` has to be a `NavHostFragment` not a regular `Fragment`. So by passing, `this` (being `B`), it wasn't getting a `NavFragment`, just a regular `Fragment`. I thought the method would have extracted the `navhost` from whatever `fragment` was passed. Guess the documentation caused a bit of confusion. To get the correct `navhost`, I had to get the `navhost` from the fragment manager like so `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(navHostResId)` (in my case, `navHostResId` was the `id` of the fragment container in `B`). Then everything worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use: NavigationUI with jetpack, i recommend this,  https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation with nav_graph.xml with NavigationDirections such as:

```
val direction = FirstFragmentDirections.actionSecondFragment()
Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(direction)
```

Or you can use non-jetpack way, i do not recommend, but depending on your UI you may need it:

```
fun displayChildFragment(frameId: Int, fragment: Fragment) {
  requireActivity().supportFragmentManager?.let {
    val transaction = it.beginTransaction()
    //transaction.setTransition(TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    transaction.replace(frameId, fragment).commit()
   }
}
```